# Optimal design pattern for multiple integrations

Tags: node.js, express, salesforce

I have an Node Express API that's kind of acting like a broker. It's responsible for syncing data between multiple systems.

In chronological order...the following has to happen (and I'm triggering this with `node-cron`)

1. Express API downloads data from an ERP and upserts it into its own Mongo Instance
   a. Some operations are done here with Mongo
2. Express API then has to download data from Salesforce (and also upserts it into its own DB)
   b. More calculations are performed
3. Express API sends Bulk API upsert request to Salesforce
4. Express API sends Bulk API update request to Salesforce

As you can see this is messy and a lot can go wrong if one part breaks. Currently, I'm calling each job a few minutes apart from each other to ensure all data has finished being downloading/processed. What's a better way to do this? Only continue if some field is set?

Comment: Why not await each step before continuing. If some can occur in parallel, you can `await Promise.all([prom1, prom2])` before moving on...

Comment: Mm...I haven't used `Promise.all` that often, but I always imagined its use case would be for something like Bulk requests to a DB. That being said, I suppose it could work for interacting with multiple independent APIs via network

Comment: My point was just to have job b wait for job a to finish (where job b depends on job a). I just added that where job c depends on a and b but a and b don't depend on each other, you can use `Promise.all` to wait for them both to finish before executing c